# Automatically open outline of PDF created with PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I'm implementing a feature to merge a bunch of PDFs into a single one, and i've already managed to merge them and generate an outline for the resulting file.

However, some users struggle to find the open outline button on some readers, so i'm trying to find a way to automatically open the outline when the PDF is opened.

Is there a way to do that ? The PDF is generated with Apache PDFBox 2.0.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
document.getDocumentCatalog().setPageMode(PageMode.USE_OUTLINES);
```

Comment: Didnt work on Chrome's integrated pdf reader. But since it worked on all my other readers, i assume it's a chrome problem. Thanks!